# XSLT Incorrect out for matching records containing letters

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello i have an XSLT that looks like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record[translate(employeeNumber, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHILKLMNOIPQRSTUVWXYZ!£$%^', '')]" priority="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="record[string-length(employeeNumber) &lt; 8]" priority="2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see there are to match conditions must not contain a letter or special charactor and much be greater than 8 charactors. So when i use this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <records>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>12345678</employeeNumber>
        </record>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>1234567A</employeeNumber>
        </record>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>12345678A</employeeNumber>
        </record>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>123456789</employeeNumber>
        </record>
    </records>
</request>
```

It should return this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <records>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>1234567A</employeeNumber>
        </record>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>12345678A</employeeNumber>
        </record>
        <record>
            <employeeNumber>123456789</employeeNumber>
        </record>
    </records>
</request>
```

**HOWEVER** it actaully returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <records/>
</request>
```

Why is the match not:

1. Looking for only letters
2. Not using the second match for charactors for more than 8?

Comment: In the last template you need to change `&lt; 8` to `&lt;= 8` .

Comment: Your question 1. has almost no meaning -- you want a `record` with `employeeNumber` "12345678A" not ignored but you are asking: "Why is the match 1.Looking for only letters" ??? Could you edit the question and expain what is the resquirement for this transformation? Obviously you *do* want a `employeeNumber` containing both digits and letters to be processed, but then you contradict yourself saying that there must be "only letters". Please, edit and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<xsl:template match="record[string-length(employeeNumber) &lt;= 8]
                           [translate(employeeNumber, '0123456789', '') = '']
" />
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
<xsl:template match="record[
  not(
    string-length(employeeNumber) &gt;= 8
    and
    translate(employeeNumber, '0123456789', '') = ''
  )
]" />
```

You don't need two templates and you don't need template priorities for this task.

The above produces:

```
<request>
  <records>
    <record>
      <employeeNumber>12345678</employeeNumber>
    </record>
    <record>
      <employeeNumber>123456789</employeeNumber>
    </record>
  </records>
</request>
```

which is consistent with your requirement

- must not contain a letter or special character
- must be not be shorter than 8 characters

Comment: You don't need two templates, but putting different rules in different templates is good practice because it keeps things modular.

Answer (score 0):

The string-length(employeeNumber) < 8 template is never matched because none of your employee numbers has a string length less than 8.

The translate() template is matching all records, because all your employee numbers contain at least one character (a digit) which is not eliminated by the translate(). (So the result of the translate is a non-empty string, whose boolean value is true).

(Note: Saxon has an option -T which traces which elements are matched by which template rules. This can be very useful for debugging this kind of thing)

Comment: hes using this match so that no copy of is made!

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this absolutely correct answer -- there are weird people in SO. +1.